# Threaded one-time variable assignment with multiple listeners in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I have a class of type `Variable` which contains an field of type `Value`, which initially is unset (`null`) but will be set at some point in the future. Multiple threads may have access to one `Variable`-object. A method with the signature `Variable.Set(Value v)` is called exactly once and sets the variable. Many other threads should be able to call `Variable.Wait()` *(both before and after the `Variable` is set)* which:

- if the `Variable` is already set, should return immediately.
- if the `Variable` is not set, should wait (efficiently) for it to be set, and then return.

As I am looking at the API, I am sure that there is some obvious synchronization primitive around – monitors, events, wait handles or similar – but I need help figuring out the simplest, most efficient solution as I am learning about parallelism in .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Servy's answer, I ended up using a private `TaskCompletionSource<Value>` inside the `Variable` class. Furthermore I applied the [async-await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) pattern with tasks in my entire application, so instead of a `Wait()`-method I had a  `Task<Value> Value()` field, like so:

```
class Variable
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<Value> source;
    public Task<Value> Value
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Variable() // Constructor
    {
        taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Value>();
        Value = taskSource.Task;
    }

    public void Set(Value val) // Called exactly once
    {
        source.SetResult(val); // Triggers task completion
    }
}
```

Comment: This class isn't adding anything over just using a `TaskCompletionSource` directly.

Comment: Correct. There is a bunch of other stuff in my class which I omitted for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Lazy` type to allow some specific value to be computed through some long running work and have any number of threads wait for the value, or use the already computed value.

Comment: I checked the API but I don't see how that will help me? The `Variable` and the `Value` are initialized at different parts in the code. The `Variable.Set` method will be called from elsewhere at some point after the `Variable` is initialized.

Comment: @Betamos Then use a `TaskCompletionSource` to set a `Task<T>`.

Comment: Thank you! `TaskCompletionSource` was exactly what I needed. I will post an answer explaining how I did it.